# trying to call a method in the where of a linq statment

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Below is the code I'm using but it replies with

> Method 'Boolean isUser(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Any help? Btw I'm using **linq to SQL** data source

```
public void dataBind()
{
    using (var gp = new GreatPlainsDataContext())
    {
        var emp = from x in gp.Employees
                  let k = isUser(x.ID)
                  where x.ActivtyStatus == 0
                  && isUser(x.ID) != false
                  orderby x.ID
                  select new
                  {
                      ID = x.ID,
                      Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName
                  };
        ListView1.DataSource = emp;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public static bool isUser(string ID)
{
    int temp;
    bool x = int.TryParse(ID, out temp);
    return x;
}
```

I found a solution to query the result of the first query as objects but is that good cause I will passing through my data twice.

---

the updated code that worked in the end after using the like as advised by Anders Abel

```
public void dataBind()
    {
        using (var gp = new GreatPlainsDataContext())
        {
            var emp = from x in gp.Employees
                      where x.ActivtyStatus == 0
                      && SqlMethods.Like(x.ID, "[0-9]%")
                      orderby x.ID
                      select new
                      {
                          ID = x.ID,
                          Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName
                      };
            ListView1.DataSource = emp;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the possible values for Employees.ID, and why does a string that is parseable to an int mean that an employee is a user?

Comment: @spender regarding the what part a user will have an id like "11064" will a team will have "oss". regarding the why part I came and the system was built like that on great plains :(

Comment: The legacy system curse in action once a gain. If checking if it's only numbers in the field is enough, you can use a LIKE expression. I've updated my answer with info and a link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq-to-sql translates the query into SQL. It only knows how to translate a limited set of built in functions. You have to rewrite your query to not include a function of your own.

A complete list of the linq-to-sql supported functions and operators can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386970.aspx).

You can use `SqlMethods.Like()` to check if the field only contains digits. See [T-SQL IsNumeric() and Linq-to-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329580/t-sql-isnumeric-and-linq-to-sql) for an example.

Comment: +1 the UDF at the given link using `IsNumeric` is probably the best solution in this case. If it used often a View or Computed Column may be of use here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're having is that because the query needs to be ran on the database, you can only use things that will work on the database, the C# code in your `isUser` method can't run on the database.

You'll have to re-write it without using that function. Perhaps you have a table listing users by IDs you could join on?

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to you query for `ID` valid for you, **for example** `where ID > 0`, recover results, and after on the resulted collection execute the hypothetical filter you want with

```
isUser(x.ID)
```

cause, I presume, it executes more complex validation somehow.

Important, that from DB results are *less as possible*, to avoid data transmission latency.

Answer (score 0):

You could call this code:

```
var emp = from x in gp.Employees
                  where x.ActivtyStatus == 0
                  orderby x.ID
```

And obtain a valid result, since every linq expression can be applied to Employees through linq to sql. Then you can cast emp to a list or and array and filter the collection using your method isUser.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can call any sql UDF(user defined function) in-line within LINQ queries like `gp.isUser(x.ID)`, so you can define this function `isUser` as a SQL UDF, something like:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION isUser(@id int)
 RETURNS bit;
 AS
 BEGIN
    if exists(select * from Users where userId = @id)
    begin 
          return 1; --true the user exists;
    else 
          return 0; --false doesn't exist;
    end
 end
```

Then you have to [define this UDF in your `.DBML` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386954.aspx) that contains other tables and procedures definition mappings. Then you can [Call it or any other UDF function inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399416.aspx) within your LINQ query Like this:

```
var emp = from x in gp.Employees
              let k = gp.isUser(x.ID)
              where x.ActivtyStatus == 0
              && gp.isUser(x.ID) != 1
              orderby x.ID
              select new
              {
                  ID = x.ID,
                  Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName + " " + x.LastName
              };
```