# IsNumeric equivalent in Linq

Tags: .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, isnumeric

I need to use a function in Linq that equivalent to IsNumeric function in SQL. What I am trying to do is get codes that matches a common pattern. The codes should be unique and they are generated by code. The pattern is like this:

ABCD0000001
ABCD0000002
...

But then user can manuplate the code and enter any character in anywhere in generated code (of course then I check the uniqueness of the code afterwards, but that is out of interest). So the records in database can be

ABCD0000001
ABCD00000T01
ABCDT0000002
..and so on.

What I want is getting the last programmatically generated (not manipulated by user) codes and retrieve the last numeric digits, so that I can add it by 1 resulting in unique code. (So the last autogenerated code is ABCD0007865 then the new code should be ABCD0007866)

I tried

```
var lastCode = (
    from c in sedc.Codes
    where SqlMethods.Like(c.Code, "ABCD" + "%")
    where Int64.TryParse(c.Code.Substring(3,10),out t)
    orderby c.Code descending
    select c)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

but this code throws an exception saying
NotSupportedException: Method 'Boolean TryParse(System.String, Int32 ByRef)' has no supported translation to SQL."

What should I do? Is my way too complicated? Is there a smarter way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL IsNumeric() and Linq-to-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329580/t-sql-isnumeric-and-linq-to-sql)

Comment: A stored procedure of user defined function is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var lastCode = (
    from c in sedc.Codes
    where SqlMethods.Like(c.Code, "ABCD[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
    orderby c.Code descending
    select c)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @GertArnold As you can see from the OP's question (`where Int64.TryParse(c.Code.Substring(3,10), out t)`) he only wants to select the codes witch follow the pattern ABCD and 7 digits.